# react stops working when directory is renamed

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into a strange problem with react. (This is done with server-side rendering)

the problem is, when I change the names of the folders/javascript files, the event handlers stop working for components.

for example:

```
reactComponents
  - componentOne
    componentOne.js
  - componentTwo
    componentTwo.js
```

assuming this works fine, when I change the name of the folder/js file name:

```
reactComponents
  - componentThreeee
    componentThreeee.js
```

after updating all places where necessary, I do a browserify build and run the project, and the component renders correctly, and binds to the correct element. But click events/ onChange events all stop working.

the annoying thing is I can't find a name pattern that breaks the component, sometimes adding dashes between words breaks it (even though other components work with a dash in their file name) other times just a regular name won't work (like 'myCustomComponent'), but then when I change the name of the file/folder, everything works as expected

has anyone else run into this problem before?