# multiple reactDom.render calls in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I had an issue yesterday that you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682879/react-stops-working-when-directory-is-renamed) and it relates. I thought that changing my directory name was messing up my react components, but I think I figured out the problem.

I'm building a web app with node/express/react and I'm rendering react server side and creating a bundle.js file to use client-side. I have multiple react components that I'm rendering on the page, but they're not all in the same 'react app'. Basically I have a few 'mini react apps' so each set of functionality has its own `ReactDom.Render` call.

for example, I have a form at the top for adding new items, that has its own render, and I have a list of items below that, that has its own render call. and both of these mini-components are bound to separate divs.

```
<div id='the-form'><%-form%></div>
<div id='the-list'><%-list%></div>
```

however, it looks like the component that comes first in the `bundle.js` is the one whose render call is working, the other component(s) render initially from the server-side rendering, but then there are no updates because the components are not re-rendering/updating.

is there a way to keep my approach but have these working?

Comment: What does your `ReactDOM.render` look like on each component? Are there any errors aside from it not updating?

Comment: @Road `if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.onload = function() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('id-of-div'));
  }
}`

Comment: @Road there are no errors

Comment: Have you tried removing `window.onload` and just use `ReactDOM.render` alone?

Comment: @Road I just did and it worked, add that as an answer and I will accept! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `window.onLoad` and just use `ReactDOM.render` alone.